# How do I create and use a symbol server?

Tags: c#, tfs, debug-symbols, symbol-server

I created a powershell script that gets all the pdb files from the drop location after the build is set to release and copies them to a folder that is shared on the network.

I also created a sample application and I added the nuget packages that contain the assemblies that I need (without the pdb files).

I found some references on the net, but I was unable to debug my assemblies using the pdb files. I am using a VPN connection to connect to the shared folder that contains the pdb files and Visual Studio 2010.

What are the exact steps that I need to make in order to use the pdb files that are shared on the network to be able to debug the assemblies that I get using nuget package manager?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a good overview of symbols, Symbol Server, and more importantly Source Server indexing, check out http://bit.ly/SymbolServerTFS which is a blog post I wrote a while back talking about all of them.  I specifically talked about it in terms of using Team Foundation Server but it's good information even if you aren't using TFS.

Also, if you want to make this experience better, please vote for my feature request on Uservoice: http://bit.ly/AtLSjl  We definitely would appreciate the added voices & votes!

Answer (score 1):

You could try, as a simple solution, VS/Tools/Options/Debugging/Symbols - and try set your symbols cache to your network share (haven't tried this before but might work, map drive etc. if needed).
At least that could get you running temporarily - and make sure you have automatically load for 'all modules' or specify yours.
hope this helps some.

Answer (score -1):

Just define it at Options->Debugging->Symbols->Symbol file (.pdb) locations

Detailed instructions on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx)

Comment: Linked resource says: "This topic is no longer available"

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this link wasn't static enough. I updated my answer with correct link.

Comment: We all have google.  we dont need a google proxy.  MSDN is worthless.  Is all marketing.  Either post an ANSWER, or find something else to do.

Comment: Someone is with a bad mood today! Can you please argue before stating that MSDN is worthless? Before googling you need to read the documentation.

Comment: You want advertisements and worthless information that will send you in circles?  Check msdn.  Clearly its not a good source of information or Stack Overflow wouldn't be inundated with questions about Microsoft products.  And yes spending 3 days at work reading useless MSDN articles with no real technical value has put me in a bad mood.