# How can I include line numbers in a stack trace when pdb files are placed at some location?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, stack-trace, pdb-files

I am keeping pdb files in different folder by some post build event.
But since pdb files are not in the folder where other exes, dlls are placed, i am not getting line number, file name in stack trace.
Please help.
Thanks in advance. 
[keeping in Debug mode]

Answer (score 0):

The simpler approach is to keep the PDB in the same directory. Alternative complicated approach is to use [Symbol Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043147/how-do-i-create-and-use-a-symbol-server).